# Still unable to connect eks instance to mongo atlas after peering VPC

Tags: mongodb, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, mongodb-atlas

I have an EKS cluster running a nodejs app that connects to a mongodb atlas database. I have successfully peered the 2 VPCs and whitelisted the AWS IP on the mongodb atlas side.

However, it is still unable to connect.

I believe that I still need to configure this final step:

[image]

How to configure the step in the green?

Comment: Might help: [Update your route tables for a VPC peering connection - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-routing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add pcx-xxx to your route table. Refer here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-vpc-peering/#in-update-your-vpc-s-route-table